# Using numpy.where() to return the indexes of a full array where the tested condition is on a sliced one

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I have the following 3 x 3 x 3 numpy array called `a` (the comments will make sense after you read the rest of the question):

```
array([[[8, 1, 0],     # irrelevant 1 (is at position 1 rather than 0)
        [1, 7, 5],     # the 1 on this line is what I am after!
        [1, 4, 9]],    # irrelevant 1 (out of the "cross")

       [[4, 0, 1],     # irrelevant 1 (is at position 2 rather than 0)
        [1, 0, 1],     # I'm only after the first 1 on this line!
        [6, 2, 1]],    # irrelevant 1 (is at position 2 rather than 0)

       [[0, 2, 2],
        [0, 6, 7],
        [3, 4, 9]]])
```

furthermore I have this list of indexes that refers to the "central cross" of said matrix, called `idx`

```
[array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 0, 1, 2, 1])]
```

EDIT: I call it "cross" as it marks the central column and row in the following:

```
>>> a[..., 0]
array([[8, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 6],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

What I would like to obtain is **the indexes of all those arrays located at `idx` whose first value is 1**, but I'm struggling in understanding how to use `numpy.where()` in the right way. Since...

```
>>> a[..., 0][idx]
array([1, 4, 1, 6, 0])
```

...I tried...

```
>>> np.where(a[..., 0][idx] == 1)
(array([0, 2]),)
```

...but as you can see it returns the index of the sliced array, not of `a`, while I would like to get:

```
[array([0, 1]), array([1, 1])]  #as a[0, 1, 0] and a [1, 1, 0] are equal to 1.
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

PS: In the comments I have been suggested to try to give a broader scenario of applicability. Although it is not what I am using for, I suppose this could be used to process images as many 2D libraries do, with a source layer, a destination layer and a mask (see for example [cairo](http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/CairoTutorial)). In this case the mask would be the `idx` array, and one might imagine working with the R channel of RGB colors (`a[..., 0]`).

Comment: Not very useful to download a question with an accepted answer (=question was understood) without explaining why. I don't care for the -2 points, but sincerely: no comment = no idea what I did wrong! :(

Comment: I provided the downvote. The "usefulness" of my downvote is with regards to the clarity of the question and its potential relevance to other users, which I feel is low.

Comment: @Benjamin - See if the last edit (at the end of the question) is of any help. As for the clarity, feel free to edit the question [I see from your profile there is a good chance you have English as your first language]. I think `"I want to know the indexes of all those arrays located at idx whose first value is 1"` is the best I can do in terms of English! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can translate the indices back using `idx`:

```
>>> w = np.where(a[..., 0][idx] == 1)[0]
>>> array(idx).T[w]
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

Comment: Your solution works flawlessly even with matrices of different shapes and different masks (`idx`). Thank you! :)